# Is there a way to disable MDDataTable's headers popup in kivymd=1.0.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm using kivy==2.2.1 and kivymd==1.0.2 because new version was creating problem in loading tha graphics in android after the apk build.

Now I'm facing the problem with the MDDataTable, any accidental tuch on the header popups tha header name and it stays in all my screens.

I want to disable it but can't find a way.

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 1]